# mongodb Problem with apt update in ubuntu

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, apt

I am facing this problem to update ubuntu and so far I tried different solutions to solve this problem but none of them could solve this problem.

```
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/4.0/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 18.66.161.40 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/5.0/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 18.66.161.40 443]
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/7.0/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 18.66.161.40 443]
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0 InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

how i can solve this problems about mongodb!I had previously installed MongoDB to install an application and then uninstalled it.

regard

Comment: try suggestions here: [apt-remove-repositories](https://linuxsimply.com/linux-basics/package-management/repository-configuration/apt-remove-repositories/) or [remove-software-repositories-ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/remove-software-repositories-ubuntu/) -- note that this is a better question for [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com)

Comment: btw it doesn't necessarily mean you aren't updating ubuntu ... these are just warnings you can ignore if you uninstalled mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my configuration I have a file

> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list

which containes this entry (in signed-by there's a path to the key)

> deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse

I added this key using the following commands:

> curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc |    sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg    --dearmor

Did you tried this? I remember that there was a change in setting key for mongodb repos because apt-key is deprecated in the newest versions of Ubuntu

Comment: tnx, this way is awesome! fantastic. great.